# For Chrome I want to use suite setup and suite tear down and for IE browser i want to use test setup and test tear down

Tags: robotframework

I have around 200 test cases written in **robot framework**, when I am executing all those in **chrome** using suite setup mentioned in settings is working fine, but in **IE** browser we are getting memory leak exceptions. So , we thought of including test setup in settings. So how to handle this situation. Is there a way to tell **RF** to use suite setup for **Chrome** and Test setup for **IE**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no built-in way to do that. You'll have to use some of the conditional keywords (eg: [Run keyword](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20If) if, etc) to perform whatever logic you need in the setup.

For example, you might configure your test and suite setup like this:

```
*** Settings ***
Suite Setup  run keyword if  $browser == "chrome"  
...  your_setup_keyword

Test Setup   run keyword unless  $browser == "chrome"  
...  your_setup_keyword
```